# Cannot load resource in jar

Tags: java, jar, zip, export

I am trying to load a resource in a jar, here is the exported jar:
[image]

'main' is the package with all my classes, and in one of those classes I am trying to load the background.png file. In my Eclipse project I put the resources under a "res/" folder, which I added to the build path to include it. When I try to use

```
new File("background.png");
```

It can't find the file.
When I use

```
MyClass.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("background.png");
```

It still can't find the file.

Comment: The `new File("relative_path")` way of opening a file depends on where you started the process from. The `MyClass.class.getClass()...` way I think requires the resources to be in the same directory as the source code, so try shifting it into the 'main' folder and see if that works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files packaged in a jar can't be accessed as `File` objects.

When you try

```
MyClass.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("background.png");
```

you are actually using the `ClassLoader` of `java.lang.Class` and not of `main.MyClass` which may not be able to find the resource (in case it is the system classloader). Try

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("background.png");
```

instead.

Comment: finally after searching the internet for hours, this solves the problem